# Query returns function plus the value inside instead of just the value

Tags: python, sql, postgresql

I'm running a select query and for fetching date and time data from the database but for some reason the returned value is `datetime.date(2021, 11, 18)` and `datetime.time(19, 19, 29)` instead of just the time and date

The current_date and current_time are instantiated as shown below:

```
time = datetime.datetime.now()
CURRENT_TIME = time.strftime('%H:%M:%S')
CURRENT_DATE = datetime.date.today()
```

The script to add the date and time data is this:

```
update_script = "UPDATE holding SET MEETINGDATE = '{}', MEETINGTIME = '{}'".format(CURRENT_DATE,CURRENT_TIME)
```

Here's the select query to fetch the data:

```
 retrieve_script = "SELECT STUDENTID,STUDENTNAME,STUDENTEMAIL,MEETINGDATE,MEETINGTIME FROM meeting1"
```

Any clue why this is so, and how can I fix it?

Comment: In your first query in python, you are updating `holding` table, in your select you are querying `meeting1` table. what is the column data type for meetingdate and meetingtime in meeting1 table ?

Comment: Executing an Update query to a postgres table is done in this manner, see answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34774409/build-a-dynamic-update-query-in-psycopg2).

Comment: also, after executing the UPDATE statement using cursor object, if you are using psycopg, you must commit , then only the update will persist.  Like so `connection.commit()`

Comment: for the various formatting of date and time in Python, refer this [article](https://www.programiz.com/python-programming/datetime/current-datetime)

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran the datatype for meetingdate is date and for meeting time is time(without timezone since I don't know how to specify timezone in the column)

Comment: Did you refer the articles above, and verify the change in table name between your update script and retrieval script? add your python code snippet to question.

Answer (score 0):

I opted use SQLAlchemy ORM to create my table as a model then generate it using `db.create_all()`

This allowed me to access individual records without the quotes for example:
Before I was getting 'John Doe' returned but now I get John Doe without the quotes.

More information can be found on the flask official documentation here https://flask-user.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data_models.html

I hope this comes in handy for someone.